# How to change Google Charts number format for controllers?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

When implementing a dashboard using Google Charts we are able to change the format of displayed quantities in tables with `google.visualization.NumberFormat()`.

However, we haven't been able to find a way to change number formats in controllers. We would like to accomplish what the image shows:

[image]

We looked in the [documentation for Google Charts controllers](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls), but we couldn't find anything helpful for this. Any help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The google API has a built in function for this.

```
options:{
    ui:{
      format:{
        prefix:'$',
      }
   }
```

Did a small fiddle for it, [link](http://jsfiddle.net/heennkkee/yhbad55v).

More info about configuration [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#--googlevisualizationnumberrangefilter) and [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference?hl=en).

Comment: You are completely right. I had not realized that was available even though I had read through the documentation you linked. Thank you very much. I've marked your answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify `ui.cssClass` option to to assign the custom CSS class to the control:

```
 programmaticSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
        'containerId': 'programmatic_control_div',
        'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Salary',
            'ui': { 'cssClass': 'currencyfilter' }
        }
    });
```

and then specify rule for a thumb label:

```
.currencyfilter .google-visualization-controls-rangefilter-thumblabel:before {
      color: brown;
      content: '$';
}
```

**Complete example**

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', { 'packages': ['corechart', 'controls'] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
      document.getElementById('programmatic_dashboard_div'));

    // We omit "var" so that programmaticSlider is visible to changeRange.
    var programmaticSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
        'containerId': 'programmatic_control_div',
        'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Salary',
            'ui': { 'labelStacking': 'vertical', 'cssClass': 'currencyfilter' }
        }
    });

    var programmaticChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'PieChart',
        'containerId': 'programmatic_chart_div',
        'options': {
            'width': 300,
            'height': 300,
            'legend': 'none',
            'chartArea': { 'left': 15, 'top': 15, 'right': 0, 'bottom': 0 },
            'pieSliceText': 'value'
        }
    });

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Name', 'Salary'],
      ['Mike', 10000],
      ['Jim', 8000],
      ['Alice', 12500],
      ['Bob', 7000]
    ]);

    var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ prefix: '$' });
    formatter.format(data, 1);

    dashboard.bind(programmaticSlider, programmaticChart);
    dashboard.draw(data);
}
```

```css
 .currencyfilter .google-visualization-controls-rangefilter-thumblabel:before {
     color: brown;
     content: '$';
 }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
 <div id="programmatic_dashboard_div" style="border: 1px solid #ccc">
   <table class="columns">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div id="programmatic_control_div" style="padding-left: 2em; min-width: 250px"></div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div id="programmatic_chart_div"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @vadim-gremyachev. That's exactly what we were looking for. Best.

Comment: Even though your solution worked perfectly fine and I thank you for it, I think that the answer by @HenrikAronsson is more clean and efficient, so I'll mark that one as the accepted one. Thanks.